# Ordenamiento de palabras en lenguaje C

Tags: c, archivo, estructuras-de-datos

tengo que realizar un programa que me permita corregir palabras mal redactadas que se encuentran dentro de un archivo .txt

Ejemplo:

Palabra mal redactada dentro del archivo .txt: "hloa"

Palabra después de ser corregida: "hola"

Necesito algún tipo de guía porque no se como empezar.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Este sitio no trabaja asi; deberías de mostrar algo del código que tienes, usando [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/56298/edit). Con lo que indicas, por mucho que queramos, es imposible ayudarte; recibirías muchas respuestas, cada una con un punto de vista distinto. Por favor, se un poco mas concreto.

Comment: Necesitarías un diccionario con TODAS las palabras correctas y a partir de ahí poder marcar cuáles son incorrectas. Un segundo paso sería buscar cuál es la más cercana para sugerirla como corrección. ¿Y qué pasa con plurales, femeninos/masculinos, verbos conjugados? Estás pidiendo un trabajo muy importante, no es para una consulta en Stack Overflow... ¿De dónde sale este requisito?

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es hacer una tabla de errores, como letras transpuestas o faltantes, para buscar la palabra correcta. Necesitas como base una [lista de palabras correctas y frecuentes](http://corpus.rae.es/frec/1000_formas.TXT). Es complicado que este garantizado que la corrección será gramatical o semanticamente correcta, pero puedes listar errores comunes sin mayor problema como primera aproximación. [En stackoverflow.com hay una discusión muy completa sobre correctores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294915/what-algorithm-gives-suggestions-in-a-spell-checker)

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/34110)

Comment: Si es una respuesta

Comment: Cabe mencionar que el texto del comentario proviene de una de las plantillas de la cola de revisión de respuestas de baja calidad, a la cual tal vez llegó por que es una respuesta relativamente corta con dos enlaces. En cualquier caso, a mí si me parece que responde la pregunta. Como sugerencia, por favor considera poner un par de líneas acerca de lo que resulta más relevante de las páginas enlazadas con base en el contexto de la pregunta.

Comment: Van a ahogar el sitio si persisten en esa actitud de etiquetar preguntas y respuestas como malas de manera tan arbitraria

Comment: Estimado. Sin ánimos de discutir, `Una posible solución es hacer una tabla de errores comunes para buscar la palabra correcta` no es una respuesta a la pregunta (este es el texto de la respuesta en el momento de la revisión). Le pido que lea atentamente el artículo ["como responder"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y ["eliminacion de respuestas"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) Ya que como verá, el sitio busca la mayor calidad posible.

Comment: Si es una respuesta pero claro depende de la definición